# 'u.Email' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

Tags: client-object-model, list-item

> 'u.Email' threw an exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

When I try to get the email from a user in a list.

Here is mycode:

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

query.ViewXml = "<View>" +
"<Query><Where>" +
"<And>" +
"<Eq>" +
"<FieldRef Name='Numero_x0020_Phone' /><Value Type='Text'>" + phonenumber + "</Value>" +
"</Eq>" +
"<Geq>" +
"<FieldRef Name='Exp' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>" +
"</Geq>" +
"</And>" +

"</Where>" +

"</Query>" +
"<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>" +
"</View>"
;

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listitems = list.GetItems(query);
context.Load(listitems, items => items.Include(item => item["MyUser"]));
context.ExecuteQuery();
User u = null;
foreach (ListItem item in listitems)
{
    FieldUserValue fuv = (FieldUserValue)item["MyUser"];
    u = context.Web.EnsureUser(fuv.LookupValue);
    res = u.Email;
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should request for additional details

```
context.Load(u, usr => usr.Email);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: #Amal Hashim where exactly should I put this code?

Comment: Inside the for loop before you accedd u.Email